# Prove that if $o(a)=m, o(b)=n$ and $gcd(m,n)=1$ then $o(ab)=mn$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove that if $o(a)=m, o(b)=n$ and $gcd(m,n)=1$ then $o(ab)=mn$

I am asking this because I saw someone asked a similar question and was told that the statement is wrong.

I managed to show quite quickly that $o(ab)|mn$, but no matter what I tried I was not able to show the equality.

Is there a mistake in the statement?

Comment: Probably the condition $ab=ba$ has to be added.

Comment: This is missing context.  If the group is abelian, sure.  If not?  There's not a lot you can say about the order of $ab$ if $a,b$ don't commute.

Comment: If $a,b$ don't commute, then $ab$ may have infinite order.

Comment: Compare with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67180/order-of-product-of-two-elements-in-a-group

Comment: The abelian case is a dupe of [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/652377/242) and likely many others.

Comment: $S_3$ has elements of order $2$ and $3$ but no element of order $6$.

Answer (score 1):

**If $a,b$ commute**, then you certainly have $(ab)^{mn}=e$ so $o(ab)|mn$. Now, suppose $o(ab)=r$, so $$a^rb^r=e$$ Raising to the $m$ in both sides, gives you $b^{rm}=e$, so $n|rm$. Since $\gcd(m,n)=1$ you actually have that $n|r$.

Similarly, (by raising to the $n$ in both sides), you can prove that $m|r$.

So, you have $n|r$ and $m|r$. Since $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then you have $mn|r$, i.e. $mn|o(ab)$.